# Can't send a SMS using SmsManager in android

Tags: android

```
I want to send a sms from my android phone but it doesn't work.
```

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
        public void sendMessage(View view){

            String msg,number;
            number= "***********";
            msg="This is a message";
           try{

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg,null,null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS failed, please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

I include 'uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"'
I run this code from my android phone but it doesn't send any message.
If there is any error how can i see those error and how to fix it.
Please Help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the permission to send/read SMS?

Comment: I include 'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"'

Comment: do you have enough balance to send message?

Comment: yes,But my phone is a dual Sim system.Before run the application i turn off Sim1.Then run the application

Answer (score 0):

[use this website for reference](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the problem is that you haven't called the `sendMessage` method.

You need to have an action that occurs when you click a button. Google how that is done on Android. Once you have that worked out, you should be able to make the button click to call the `sendMessage` method.

Also, you'll need to know how to view the error log. There are a number of apps that allow you to do this. It is important to know how to view the error log so that way if your Toast finally pops up, you'll be able to check the log to see why this happened.

Comment: I solve the problem.Actually the problem is for dual sim. And always i deactivate my first sim(Sim1). But this is the problem.My app always find my first sim message center number but i deactivate Sim1.Now i activate my first sim and this is worked.Thanks to all for your answer and help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the sendMessage() some where in the code if you trigger a button click?  sendTextMessage work well. Anyway, make sure that you've validated if number is null or bad formatted. This may causes the problem. Make also sure that you are using the proper SMSMAnager (android.telephony.SmsManager) instead of     android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager. SEND_SMS permission is also required.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.Actually the problem is for dual sim. And always i deactivate my first sim(Sim1). But this is the problem.My app always find my first sim message center number but i deactivate Sim1.Now i activate my first sim and this is worked.Thanks to all for your answer and help